# Remove the required conditions from registration

Tags: magento-2.1, validation, registration

I want to remove required condition on Prename and Surname and only want to use the company name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

1 Override below template to your theme

\vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\widget\name.phtml

**Find Below**

```
<input type="text" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFieldId('firstname') ?>"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFieldName('firstname') ?>"
                   value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>"
                   title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?>"
                   class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') ?>" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFieldParams() ?> <?php if ($block->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') == 'required-entry') echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
```

**Replace with**

```
<input type="text" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFieldId('firstname') ?>"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFieldName('firstname') ?>"
                   value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>"
                   title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?>"
                   class="input-text" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFieldParams() ?> >
```

You can follow same things for last name.

After you have to run below query into database

```
1. UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'firstname' and `entity_type_id` = 1;
2. UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'last' and `entity_type_id` = 1;
```